# Deploying JHipster Project in to tomcat server

Tags: java, spring-boot, deployment, microservices, jhipster

I have 3 spring boot JHipster microservices projects which are currently being deployed to openshift. Now, I want to deploy my JHipster microservices project to tomcat instead of deploying it to openshift. I googled all over the internet but was unable to find any suitable solution for it. Currently, I am using JHipster version 6.8.0. Please point me in the correct direction. Reposting for better reach

Answer (score 0):

To deploy any spring boot application to a JEE container you must build the application into a WAR and you must have a configuration class which extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` and override `protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)` method.

REF: [What about the Java EE Application Server?](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications#what-about-the-java-ee-application-server)